# Issue in detecting application from website

Tags: java, android, html, redirect

I want to detect whether application is present or not from website.
Facing issue in detecting application from website,there is no event on button click this is my piece of html code:

```
 <a href="intent:#Intent;scheme=start;package=com.xyz.star;end">click here</a>
Launch App
</a>
```

and this is piece of code in **Manifest File:**

```
    <activity
        android:name=".activity.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <data android:scheme="startci" />
            <action android:name="com.xyz.CUSTOMACTION" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
        </intent-filter>

    </activity>
```

Appreciate for help.There is very less solution regarding this issue and not getting proper solution.